# Ajax validation and SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<' on Laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, ajaxform

It's my first time with JQuery and Ajax validation in Laravel. I'm trying to validate a form using Laravel Request rules.
Seems the server validate the fields because it sends me back the errors when I don't fill up the requests ones but when I do it I get this error on the console **SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<'**

That's the code I wrote:

**TechnicianFormRequest**

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'nome' => 'required',
        'cognome' => 'required',
        'ruolo_principale' => '',
        'antincendio' => '',
        'primosoccorso' => '',
        'rischioelettrico' => '',
        'lavoroinquota' => '',
        //
    ];
```

**TechnicianController (store method)**

```
public function store(TechnicianFormRequest $request)
{

    $validated = $request->validated();

    $technician = Tecinfo::create($validated);

    return redirect()->action('TechnicianController@index')->with('success', 'Tecnico aggiunto con successo!');
    // return dd($request->all());

}
```

**Ajax Code:**
(can't paste js code, so I add a pic)

[Ajax code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9Rf4.png)

Thank you to everyone who will help me

Valerio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are parsing `Json` in your `ajax` but not returning `json` from your `store` method

As Per Laravel Documentation:

> The `json` method will automatically set the `Content-Type` header to `application/json`, as well as convert the given array to JSON using the `json_encode` PHP function

Use below in your controller to return `json`

```
return response()->json([
    'success' => 'Tecnico aggiunto con successo!',
]);
```

Comment: may I also ask you how can I redirect to the index method?..thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @netnull why do you want to redirect it to `index` method if you are using `ajax?`

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but how can I show in the list the person I've stored without reload the page ?

Comment: thank you @Sehdev for right answer, it saved my time a lot.
@netnull in response to your comment about redirecting to index page you can add this line in your ajax success method

`window.location.href = {{ route('your-index-route-name') }}`

Comment: @HamidAli sure. Sure, here it is:  **Unexpected token '{'. Expected a property name.** That's what I wrote on my js file under the success part : **window.location.href = {{ action('addTechnician') }};**

Comment: @netnull wrap this in a string quotes like this ` '{!! action("action-name-here") !!}' `